# Home button event in HTC Smart, delivered to my own app?

Tags: c++, c, brew-framework, brewmp

I want to get an event to my application when someone presses the Home button:
[image: Stock HTC Smart photo]

<sup>(The silvery button with an arrow pointing left is the Home Button on the HTC Smart.)</sup>

However, when I press the button, no event *at all* arrives to my app. If I connect the system logger, I see that the Brew MP OS itself detects something, but it does not arrive to my app.

```
[CORE] CoreDaemon_HandleEvent: 111
[CORE] CoreDaemon_HandleEvent: 112
```

Can I register with these events so the OS passes them on to me? (Or whatever it takes to detect the home button in my app.)

I suspect the `[ISHELL_RegisterNotify][2]` function may be what I am looking for, but I don't know how to use it. I tried:

```
ISHELL_RegisterNotify(piShell, AEECLSID_OF_MY_APP, AEECLSID_CORE, NMASK_SHELL_KEY |(NOTIFIER_VAL_ANY << 16));
```

That didn't work, neither this:

```
ISHELL_RegisterNotify(piShell, AEECLSID_OF_MY_APP, AEECLSID_CORE, ~0);
```

I kind of hoped that last one would get me all "core" events, but neither of those two made any difference at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app will first receive an `EVT_KEY` with wParam=63620 and then immediately get the `EVT_APP_SUSPEND` event.

Hence, as far as I understand, the "Home Button" can not be used in any meaningful way by Brew applications for input.